# In Firebase how to get currently logged in user from from custom jwt token auth

Tags: firebase

I'd like to secure my presence logic so that the app automatically sets the username/userid from the current auth token/session and has permission to only set the logged in user's presence.

1. How can I get currently logged in user's info from the Firebase class when we are outside of the scope of the auth method?

```
myConnectionsRef.childByAppendingPath(Fierbase.currentUserId) //there is no such thing as Firebase.currentUserId
```

2. How can I set up the permissions so that a user only updates their own child node and not others - is the following the right way:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "members":
    {
      "$room_id": {
        ".read": "auth.uid !== null"
         "$member_id" : {
             ".write": "auth.uid === $member_id"
          }
      }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read about this in the docs, under the section titled [Monitoring Authentication State](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication). What is here is just a re-iteration of the existing docs.

Use the onAuth() method to listen for changes in user authentication state.

```
// Create a callback which logs the current auth state
function authDataCallback(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
  } else {
    console.log("User is logged out");
  }
}
// Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes
var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com");
ref.onAuth(authDataCallback);
```

Additionally, you can use the getAuth() method to synchronously check authentication state.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com");
var authData = ref.getAuth();
if (authData) {
  console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
} else {
  console.log("User is logged out");
}
```